# Create new column if column contains on or more of multiple strings from a vector

Tags: r, string, text, dplyr, text-mining

I am trying to classify hospitality data.

My dataset looks something like the dataset below and is approx. 400000 rows long.

```
dataset<-data.frame(id=c(1001:1005), Role_title = c("Head Chef","Nurse",
        "Latin America Travel Sales Consultants \xfc\xbe\x8c\xb6\x84\xbcK OTE \xfc\xbe\x8c\xb6\x84\xbcK","Cooks Wanted","Calling all waiters"))
```

The terms I am looking for are stems as well as full strings and the vector is approx 100 rows long.

```
terms=c("chef","cook","wait")
```

I would like to create a new column 'Contains terms' which places a 1 into 'Contains terms' if the one or more strings from the vector is matched or partially matched  Row 'Role_title', and a 0 if it does not, so that the dataset will look like the below.

```
dataset<-data.frame(id=c(1001:1005), Role_title = c("Head Chef","Nurse",
      "Acting Director Sales","Cooks Wanted","Calling all waiters"),
        Contains_terms=c(1,0,0,1,1))
terms=c("chef","cook","wait")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stri_detect` from `stringi` to return a logical vector after `paste`ing the 'terms' vector to create the `pattern`, convert the logical `vector` to binary by wrapping with `as.integer`

```
library(stringi)
transform(dataset, Contains_terms = as.integer(stri_detect(toupper(Role_title), 
         regex=paste(toupper(terms), collapse="|"))))
#    id                Role_title Contains_terms
#1 1001                 Head Chef              1
#2 1002                     Nurse              0
#3 1003 Acting     Director Sales              0
#4 1004              Cooks Wanted              1
#5 1005       Calling all waiters              1
```

---

Or another option with `grep` (also if there are many elements in 'terms'

```
as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(toupper(terms), `grepl`, 
                 x=toupper(dataset$Role_title))))
#[1] 1 0 0 1 1
```

---

If we want to do processing for elements in "Role_title" that have only "ASCII" characters (based on the updated dataset in the OP's post)

```
i1 <- stri_enc_mark(dataset$Role_title)=="ASCII"
i1
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
dataset$Contains_terms[i1] <-  as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(toupper(terms), `grepl`, 
                 x=toupper(dataset$Role_title[i1]))))
dataset$Contains_terms
#[1]  1  0 NA  1  1
```

Comment: An additional question is how to ensure all Role_title terms are characters (eg  "Assistant Caf\xe9 Manager Rose Bay NSW") Have just edited code to  reflect this.

Comment: Have tried the following but is not removing the unwanted elements: dataset$Role_title<-gsub('[[:digit:]]', "", dataset$Role_title)
dataset$Role_title<-gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", dataset$Role_title)

Comment: @MonikaSarder  The update gives me something like `Latin America Travel Sales Consultants ü¾Œ¶„¼K OTE ü¾Œ¶„¼K`.  Can you update with dput of the example

Comment: what could I do to remove all of these rows with a "\" element in them. There are only a handful?

Comment: @MonikaSarder  Actually it is just utf-8 characters and not "\"  i.e. `v1 <- c("Assistant Caf\xe9 Manager Rose Bay NSW")
 v1
#[1] "Assistant Café Manager Rose Bay NSW"`

Comment: The utf-8 characters are stopping the code from working. Is there a way to remove them or the code you have provided to work over them. There are actually 1,439,000 rows so too many to change manually

Comment: @MonikaSarder If you want to remove those rows, you can use `grep` i.e. `v1 <- c("Assistant Caf\xe9 Manager Rose Bay NSW", "Something else")
 i1 <- grepl("^[A-Za-z ]+$", v1); i1
  #[1] FALSE  TRUE`  Use the i1 to subset the dataset rows.

Comment: @MonikaSarder  You can also read the dataset with `encoding = "utf-8"` in `read.table`

Comment: @MonikaSarder  I updated the post.  Please check if that works for you.

Comment: the new code worked. will try and eliminate those in pre-processing next time.